# Use a member of struct vector in nested classes

Tags: c++

I have written some codes like this

```
struct connectedGrids
{
    int Coord[3];
    enum faceOrien_Type
    {
        xNeg = 0,
        xPos = 1,
        yNeg = 2,
        yPos = 3,
        zNeg = 4,
        zPos = 5
    }faceOrien;
};

class  face
{
public:
    vector<connectedGrids> ConnectedGrids;
};

class grid
{
public:
    face Face;
}
```

I have initialized an object Grid in the main.cpp

```
vector<vector<vector<grid> > > Grid = initGrid();
```

And I want to call the member of struct vector in nested classes like this:

```
Grid[i][j][k].Face.ConnectedGrids.faceOrien = 1;
```

But it gave me an error saying

> faceOrien is not the member of std::vector<_Ty>

I'm new to C++, and I can't get out where is wrong :(

Comment: Convention is to start classes names with capital letter, not variables, members and methods/functions. At least according to my experience. ;)

Comment: I'm new to Computer Programming so I don't know much about Convention, is there any convention generally accepted by most programmers? Thanks :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid[i][j][k].Face.ConnectedGrids is a vector. It surely doesn't have faceOrien member. You should add something to the vector and then access its elements, for example:

```
Grid[i][j][k].Face.ConnectedGrids.push_back(connectedGrids());
Grid[i][j][k].Face.ConnectedGrids[someIndex].faceOrien = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, `ConnectedGrids` is a vector, you declared it as

```
vector<connectedGrids> ConnectedGrids;
```

So, which of the `connectedGrids` structures *inside* that vector did you want to modify?

Comment: Yes you're right, so if I want to declare a vector using connectedGrids as members, how should I write the code? And how should I use each member inside this vector?

Comment: structs and classes have _members_: they are _named_ subobjects with number, type, size and offset fixed at compile time. Vectors and arrays have _elements_, which are identified by an index, and don't have distinct names.

Comment: So, you can't declare a vector with members at all. But, say it has 100 elements (all of type `connectedGrids`, indexed 0..99). Which one of those elements to you want to change? The first? The last? All 100 of them?

Answer (score 2):

`ConnectedGruds` is an `vector<connectedGrids>`, but you are treating it like a `connectedGrids` object.

```
Grid[i][j][k].Face.ConnectedGrids[0].faceOrien = 1;
//                               ^^^  assumes size > 0
```